# Compile assembly code from C code without using specific register in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation

I am injecting some control flow monitoring codes to a program. I get an assembly code generated by GCC C compiler (flag -S). Then I add some monitoring codes in assembly before every indirect branches within the application. Those monitoring codes needs to use some registers and therefore, for every branch I inject the code I have to push and pop the registers I use in order to save the previously written value and return them after.

However since the performance is an issue, I was wondering if I can avoid the push pops when I convert the C code to assembly code and tell the GCC to generate assembly code without using one or two specific register. Therefore, I can avoid using push pops for every indirect branch to save the existing values in the register.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, see [global register variables in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html).

Comment: I see but I guess that does not answer my question. I do not want to modify the C code. I just want to tell the compiler to do not use specific registers. For example you might be able to do it for certain codes with reducing the optimization level of the C code. But thats not what I want either.

Comment: It's trivial to stick that into a separate file and use `-include` compiler option to, you know, include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`-ffixed-reg`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) option.

Note that if the register in question is required to be used for passing arguments, etc, this won't work (indeed, it appears that in that case, gcc will silently use it anyway).